# Hibernate query.executeQuery() giving unknown SQLException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, micronaut

I have two model classes, applied inner join on them using sql native query.
Query is working fine on SQLServer console, but as i integrated it in micronaut application's ORM (hibernate) it starts giving Error queue_id not defined, even though queue_id does not exists in model classes and native query.

Stats.groovy

```
    @Entity
    class Stats {
    
        Date reportingTime
        int callsAbandoned
        int callsReceived
        int callsAnswered
        int serviceCallsOffered
        int serviceCallsAbandoned
        int serviceLevelCalls
        int callsDequed
        float serviceLevel
    
        @ManyToOne
        @javax.persistence.Column(name = "skill_group_id")
        Queue queue;
    
        static constraints = {
            callsAbandoned(nullable: false)
            callsReceived(nullable: false)
            callsAnswered(nullable: false)
            serviceCallsOffered(nullable: false)
            serviceCallsAbandoned(nullable: false)
            callsDequed(nullable: false)
            queue(nullable: false)
            serviceLevelCalls(nullable: false)
        }
    }
```

Queue.groovy

```
    @Entity
    class Queue {
    
        String name
        @Column(name = "cisco_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        String id
        AgentGroup agentGroup
        Integer serviceLevel, poolType, serviceLevelPercentage, serviceLevelType;
    
        static hasOne = [stats: QueueStats]
        static hasMany = [cceAgents: Agent,historicalStats: QueueStatsHistoricalCcx, stats:Stats]
        static belongsTo = Agent
    
        static mapping = {
            sort name: 'asc'
            version false
        }
    
        static constraints = {
            agentGroup nullable: true
            serviceLevelPercentage nullable:true
            serviceLevelType nullable:false
        }
    }
```

Query:

```java
    String query = "select SUM(serviceCallsAbandoned) as serviceCallsAbandoned, SUM(serviceCallsOffered) as serviceCallsOffered, SUM(serviceLevelCalls) as serviceLevelCalls, 
SUM(callsDequed) as routerCallsDequeued, queue as id from Stats";
```

Query works fine if I remove `queue as id`, but gives unknown error with it and that is shown below:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'queue_id'.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'queue_id'.
```

using below method for executing query:

```
Stats.withNewSession {
    list = Stats.executeQuery(query)
}
```

Hibernate = v5.1.9.Final

Gorm = v6.1.9.Release

Comment: It isn't clear if you are using GORM or Micronaut Data.  The code looks like GORM code but the question mentions "as i integrated it in micronaut application's ORM (hibernate)".

Comment: Framework is micronaut but I Used GORM for persistence layer.

Comment: https://medium.com/@S1lv3rd3m0n/micronaut-groovy-with-gorm-3a2d0b12e86b
Here is the example of it. how we use gorm with micronaut framework

Comment: Thanks.  I understand how to use GORM with Micronaut.  I was asking to clarify that is what you are doing.  Thank you for the clarification.